# Restore EditText input in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with fragment. Fragment adds to activity like this, depending on some data:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        switch (someId) {
            case 1:
                mFragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case 2:
                mFragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
        }
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.e("onSaveInstanceState Activity", "not null");
        mFragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mFragment");
    }

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(SOME_TEXT, "example text");
    mFragment.setArguments(args);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, mFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState Activity", "onSave");
    getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mFragment", mFragment);
}
```

And then in fragments (assume they are identical):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Bundle in = getArguments();
    String field1Text = in.getString(SOME_TEXT);
    field1 = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.field1);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.e("savedInstanceState", "not null");
        field1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("field1"));
    } else {
        Log.e("savedInstanceState", "null");
        field1.setText(field1Text);
    }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState", "onSave");
    outState.putString("field1", field1.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

So I thought that fragment would restore its state and setText to EditText field.
But for example when I instantiate fragment with bundle's SOME_TEXT = `"example text"`, then change it to `"some changes"` in EditText's field, then I move to other app (causing my app to close when memory is low for example):

`onSaveInstanceState onSave`

is called but `onSaveInstanceState Activity` is not.

and when I open it again text in EditText is `"example text"` and in logs I have:

`savedInstanceState not null
 savedInstanceState null`

(It seems that `onActivityCreated` is fired twice in my case)
but `onSaveInstanceState Activity not null` is not called.

so why that text is not as same as I want.

How should I do to restore EditText's field?

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate() for the activity, you must call the super function.  That re-attaches fragments from the SavedInstanceState.

Notice you are performing a second fragment transaction after the re-attachment.  You are manually pulling the saved fragment out of the bundle and re-attaching it.  You don't need to do that.

That's the problem because a fragment added through a fragment transaction will receive a null savedInstanceState bundle.  Meaning the fragment will have no state to implement in it's onCreate(). You can just skip doing any fragment transaction in the onCreate when savedInstanceState != null.  And make sure to call the super.onCreate() in the fragment as well.

Comment: Now I skip all transactions if `saveInstanceState != null`. But when I move to other app `saveInstanceState` in my activity not called (`savedInstanceState` in fragment is called). Please, see updated question.

Comment: Not sure why your activity savedInstance isn't being called (double check that?).  But besides that you can remove getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mFragment", mFragment);  Calling the super in SavedInstanceState saves the fragment for you.

Comment: I checked `void onSaveInstanceState` in my other activity with fragment (implemented like in my question) and it's called when I move to other app. And that behaviour described in my question is strange and I have no idea why is it so.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment, yet here is my suggestion:
Are you sure that

> savedInstanceState null

is called inside "first" fragment? I mean, don't you accidently create another fragment which replaces the old one?

Comment: I think that you are right. New fragment replaces old one (which restored text). But how can I avoid that? That is the question.

Comment: Well, it depends on when you instantiate fragments. If it is inside onCreate method in the Activity, you can use such approach:
`onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   if(savedInstance == null){
   //perform setup
   }
}`

Comment: It's inside onCreate. I tried to do [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack). But when I move to other app `onSaveInstanceState` in Activity is not called.

Comment: Updated my question with `onSaveInstanceState` from activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnCreate() method following the super call you need to add

this.setRetainInstance(true);

That will allow the fragment to retain the state and should save any changes that have been made.

Also in a fragment it's not the onCreate method that does the initial load it is the onCreateView() method.

Comment: Views that don't use setRetainInstance(true) also keep their view states when saved by SaveInstanceState (e.g. View hierarchy, child fragments, textView text, etc).

Comment: When I move to other app `onSaveInstanceState` in my activity not called (`onSaveInstanceState` in fragment is called). Do you have any ideas why is it so?