# Fragment closes after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I found some similar questions here but I couldn't find something specific for my own problem.

I have a `FragmentActivity` where I have the container for the my fragments. Initialy it loads a `MainFragment` from which you can navigate to other fragments. The problem occurs when I go from the initial `MainFragment` to another `Fragment`, then after screen orientation changes the current `Fragment` closes and `MainFragment` starts. **It does not give any error messages in the  log**, so it does not crash it just closes!

Some of the similar solutions show that I have to recreate all the fragments inside the `onCreate` from the `FragmentActivity`using the `savedInstanceState`.

Do I really have to do it like that or is there an alternative solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to handle orientation changes http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: You see MainFragment again because the activity gets recreated and it is loaded on the onCreate as default fragment

Comment: There is http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/3225458 I think the best way to keep your app state.