# Fragment and Fragment on BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

**CONSTRUCTION**

`Activity A` holds `Fragment A` that is able add `Fragment B` on backstack.

**PROBLEM**

`Fragment B` holds `Views` generated via API response.
State of these `Views` is what I need to be able to recreate after rotation or when going back to `Fragment A` by using `onBackPressed` and lunching `Fragment B` again.

I've read quite some of the topics on SO about `Fragments` in backstack and I am aware of their inability to retain instance.

What should I do to achieve such outcome?

Comment: use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and start new fragment with hide + add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fragments` on backstack can always retain instance if you save it. An `Activity` or a `Fragment` on a backstack in simply in a paused state. So you want to save the data/variables in the `onSaveInstanceState` method for that class (you will be overriding it).

Now to restore from the saved state you would have noticed that the `onCreate`, `onCreateView` for Activity, Fragment, respectively, have a `Bundle savedInstanceState` parameter being passed in. This is where you saved your state in the previous step, thus, you can add

`if (savedInstanceState != null) { 
//TODO: restore the state 
}`

to your onCreate/onCreateView method and you should be good to go.

Comment: This link might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack

Comment: that link was really helpful, but I still don't know how to retain this layouts. Problem is that some of them are Switches, EditTexts, CheckBox how should I save such data? Most of them are even inside additional containers(LinearLayout).

Comment: The way to do it would be to save the state of the data they were showing (eg. Switch is selected or unselected, a LinearLayout / RelativeLayout contains a child view or not and if it does then which one, what is the color currently showing if that is a variable value in your case). You can save this data in your savedInstanceState and then redraw your activity/fragment with that configuration.