# ViewPager inside Fragment doesn't restore child fragments' state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I hav a problem. I have a fragment, which contains `viewpager` inside. For `viewpager` i use FragmentPagerAdapter extension. There are `recycler views` inside of each `pager fragment`. 
The question is that i can't restore scroll position after screen rotation inside `recycler views` of `viewpager`. I thought that problem is in `recyclerview`, but soon i found out that after screen rotation fragments inside `viewpager` are being recreating, so `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are  called, even though they shouldn't. I also tried use `onSaveInstanceState(bundle)` and found out that inside `onCreateView()` this bundle is always null. So what should i do?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993853/viewpager-inside-fragment-how-to-retain-state) topic didn't help me.

Comment: Could you try using mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);

Comment: @dex, i tried. it did not help me. actually, it shouldn't because viewpager saves fragments' state when i swipe it, but when i rotate screen, position is got lost. sorry for my english

Answer (score 3):

Well, i have found an answer. The problem is in me). There is hierarchy : MainActivity with frame layout for fragment - PagerFragment which contains viewpager - fagments inside viewpager. The problem is that after screen rotation inside of activity i was allways replacing PagerFragment, such as:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragment = new PagerFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but i should do this:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (fragment == null) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new PagerFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

It was completely my fault and i am ashamed. I am sorry.

Comment: Or `if (savedInstanceState == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override function in your PagerAdapter with null state.

```
override fun restoreState(state: Parcelable?, loader: ClassLoader?) {
        super.restoreState(null, loader)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two overrides should solve your problem

here you save your values

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and here you can restore it

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}
```