# Save state of fragments in backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

My problem is generally described in this question:
[Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

But i can't understand how the accepted answer is related to it.

To keep it short:

1. There are 2 fragments A and B.
2. I go from A to B using transaction.replace() and add transaction to backstack.
3. I rotate screen -> fragment A is not visible, but it's onSaveInstanceState is called - everything ok up to this point.
4. I rotate screen again. Again A's onSaveInstanceState is called, but now it's view doesn't exist so I can't save it's state.

What's the purpose of using getFragment/putFragment, as accepted answer suggests?
When my fragment is in the backstack there's no point in keeping reference to it I guess.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever work this out?