# How to handle fragment state when "Don't keep activities" is Enabled

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreate()`
e.g.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (mlist == null)
        mlist = new ArrayList<>();
    isLoading = true;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid_view, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    onEmptyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emptyText);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    setNewAdapter();

    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "Gridview populated");
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    gridView.setEmptyView(onEmptyView);
    registerForContextMenu(gridView);
    return view;
}
```

In `Activity` I am saving `fragment` using `getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(bundle, tag)` and `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(bundle, tag)`

Now when I enable "Don't keep activities" option in Developer Option
state of `fragment` is maintained but views that I am initializing in `onCreateView()` are destroyed.
HELP!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)