# Edit text in fragment gets reset after setText()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-savedstate

I'm saving the content of my EditText on rotation as

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("editTextText",mEdittext.getText().toString());
}
```

And in my onActivity created I'm trying to reset it to the previous value as

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getContext();
    View mView = getView();
    if (mView != null) {
        mEdittext = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editt_fragPend);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            String savedText=savedInstanceState.getString("editTextText","");
            mEdittext.setText(savedText);
        }
    }
}
```

I debugged the above code the value of "savedText" indeed is the value I stored in onSaveInstanceState but after setting it to the editText. It still shows up blank. I have no other code that meddles with the editText.

Comment: the value should be restored automatically if you provide unique ids for edittext

Comment: @Raghunandan If you mean give it a unique id in 'android:id='. Yes I did give it a unique ID.

Comment: yes try it out yourself

Comment: I think your fragment is regenerated on screen rotation and  the value you are setting on previous fragment view. Just add a LOG on fragment onCreateView() to check you are updating on same fragment object or not.

Comment: @AshleshaSharma ya it is getting regenerated. How do I solve this?

Comment: You could follow two steps:
1. stop fragment regeneration in activity.
or
2. stop recreation of activity and fragment on screen rotation.
here you can set flags in android manifest.

Comment: That was really vague but it helped thanks! I didn't know what to do to stop fragment regeneration. This helped
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/5618904