# Navigation drawer changes in rotation

Tags: java, android

I have two fragments MainFragment and First_Fragment. First fragment contains a video view but whenever I try to rotate, nav drawer always goes back to its main fragment. How could I save or restore my fragment state ? so it would stop going back to its main fragment.

Here's my code for the MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

VideoView videoView;
NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MainFragment first = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, first);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



}
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        MainFragment first = new MainFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, first);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        First_Fragment first = new First_Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, first);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `setRetainInstance(true)` in your fragments, but a `BottomNavigationBar` will work incorrectly. In this case you can use some boolean flag in activity and save/restore it with Bundle like this:

**In onCreate:**

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isMapFragmentVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isMainVisible");
    } else {
        navigator.navigateToFragment(fragmentLocation);
    }
```

**In onSavedInstanceState:**

```
outState.putBoolean("isMainVisible", isMapFragmentVisible);
```

**In onNavigationSelectedListener:**

```
case R.id.bottom_navigation_map:
    if (isMapFragmentVisible) {
        break;
    } else {
        navigator.navigateToFragment(fragmentMap);
        isMapFragmentVisible = true;
    }
    return true;

case R.id.bottom_navigation_location:
    if (!isMapFragmentVisible) {
        break;
    } else {
        navigator.navigateToFragment(fragmentLocation);
        isMapFragmentVisible = false;
    }
    return true;
```

For me it works perfect. Are there any more elegant ways?

Answer (score 3):

When you're not handling the activity change like orientation, keyboard, etc. it will automatically recreates the activity. Therefore you're fragment does not save your previous instance. To solve that, I only encounter two solution.

**The first one is already mentioned by Zeeshan that handle your orientation change by following this step:**

1. Handle the orientation change in your AndroidManifest

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="com.example.Activity"
       android:label="Activity"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
   ```
2. Handle the event in the `onConfiguration` Change method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

   }
   ```

**The second one is to save the fragment state. Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/5870896**

Comment: Your 1st method worked perfect. I tried many solutions, but nothing worked. You saved my day. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity recreates when you rotate the device.** you need to mention in your manifest that you will handle the orientation change in your code so that system don't do it like this:

```
<activity name="MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

and then handle the event

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

}
```

in your activity

Answer (score 0):

Write this in manifests.xml

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

like this:-

```
<activity
        android:name=".fragmentLayouts.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

Add this to your java code:-

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```