# After screen orientation change activity class member variable(Object) loss

Tags: android, android-activity, onconfigurationchanged

I have a base class for managing fragment inside my Activity. which handles fragment backstack,opening etc. but on Orientation change this object become null and i loss all my fragment state.

```
public class Dashboard extends AbstractNavDrawerActivity implements AsyncRequest
    .OnAsyncRequestComplete {

BaseFragmentOrganizer fragmentOrganizer;//object that manages backstack and other operation 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//on orientation change fragmentOrganizer becomes null so no more backstack.
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentOrganizer = new MainFragmentOrganizer(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your Activity in `manifest` file.

it won't recreate your Activity.

Comment: i am known of it. but is this only solution bcoz officially android developer not recommend this.

Comment: I don't know about that. but whatever makes your coding easy is great. that's what I believe .

Comment: for now this is only solution for me. thanks for your response.

Comment: this is the exact answer