# Why is 'onCreateView' method called in fragment after rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have implemented a list fragment inside my main activity. I open fragment by this code:

```
  fragmentTransactionChat = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        itemFragment = ChatItemFragment.newInstance(1);
        fragmentTransactionChat.add(R.id.frame_main, itemFragment, "chatFragment").commit();
    }
    else {
        itemFragment = (ChatItemFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("chatFragment");
    }
```

and this is `onCreateView` method in fragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    setRetainInstance(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
    // Set the adapter
    final Context context = view.getContext();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
        linearLayoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    } else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
    }
    mAdapter = new PostRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mListener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
    if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    }
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager, mAdapter) {
        @Override
        public void onBottomList() {
            floatingActionButton.hide();
        }
    });

    postProvider = PostProvider.getInstance(getActivity());
    postProvider.setCallListener(this);

    bindItems(view);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        postProvider.loadPost();
    }
    bindNotificationManager();
    return view;
}
```

My problem is when I rotate the device, `onCreateView` method is called again and mAdapter object and others are null, so it causes problem in my logic.
Note: My fragment isn't added by my main activity after rotation, because I have handled it by this condition command:

`if(savedInstanceState == null)`

What's the problem?!

Comment: Perhaps you can move you problematic adapter code to another fragment lifecycle method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/2949612

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `getActivity()` which is `null`. Try to get the activity using `((Activity) getContext())` in your `onCreateView` method.