# Why does my savedInstanceState Bundle not preserve values?

Tags: android, bundle, saving-data, onsaveinstancestate

I am making a fitness app that allows users to make lists of fitness events. One of the options when making a new event is to select the location using a Google Map. This opens a new fragment, and causes all values on the current fragment to be reset. To prevent this from happening, I save any values that have been set by using onSaveInstanceState():

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mEventStr != null)
        outState.putString("event", mEventStr);
    if (mSelectStartDateTxtVw != null)
        outState.putString("startDate", mSelectStartDateTxtVw.getText().toString());
    if (mSelectStartTimeTxtVw != null)
        outState.putString("startTime", mSelectStartTimeTxtVw.getText().toString());
    if (mSelectEndDateTxtVw != null)
        outState.putString("endDate", mSelectEndDateTxtVw.getText().toString());
    if (mSelectEndTimeTxtVw != null)
        outState.putString("endTime", mSelectEndTimeTxtVw.getText().toString());
    if (mEventType != null)
        outState.putString("eventType", mEventType);
    if (mEventDescriptionEdTxt != null)
        outState.putString("eventDescription", mEventDescriptionEdTxt.getText().toString());
}
```

Then, when the user has returned from the Google Map, I restore these values in onCreateView():

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mEventStr = savedInstanceState.getString("event");
    mSelectStartDateTxtVw.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("startDate"));
    mSelectStartTimeTxtVw.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("startTime"));
    mSelectEndDateTxtVw.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("endDate"));
    mSelectEndTimeTxtVw.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("endTime"));
    mEventType = savedInstanceState.getString("eventType");
    mEventDescriptionEdTxt.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("eventDescription"));
}
```

This, however, does not seem to work. Does anyone have an idea of why this may be happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

Comment: "This opens a new fragment" -- please explain **precisely** what you are doing to "open" a fragment. "and causes all values on the current fragment to be reset" -- please explain **precisely** what you are doing that is causing "all values" (fields?) on whatever "the current fragment" is "to be reset". The saved instance state `Bundle` is for configuration changes and related scenarios.

Comment: If you replace a fragment with another fragment, the saved state will be cleared if you don't put it on the backstack.... .....

Answer (score 0):

Call the `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` at the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by passing the selected values to the Google Map fragment, and then passing these values back to the original fragment:

```
// CreateEventFragment.java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if (mEventStr != null)
    outState.putString("event", mEventStr);
if (mSelectStartDateTxtVw != null)
    outState.putString("startDate", mSelectStartDateTxtVw.getText().toString());
if (mSelectStartTimeTxtVw != null)
    outState.putString("startTime", mSelectStartTimeTxtVw.getText().toString());
if (mSelectEndDateTxtVw != null)
    outState.putString("endDate", mSelectEndDateTxtVw.getText().toString());
if (mSelectEndTimeTxtVw != null)
    outState.putString("endTime", mSelectEndTimeTxtVw.getText().toString());
if (mEventType != null)
    outState.putString("eventType", mEventType);
if (mEventDescriptionEdTxt != null)
    outState.putString("eventDescription", mEventDescriptionEdTxt.getText().toString());

// GoogleMapFragment.java
Bundle inBundle = getArguments();
Bundle outBundle = new Bundle();
outBundle.putString("event", inBundle.getString("event"));
outBundle.putString("startDate", inBundle.getString("startDate"));
outBundle.putString("startTime", inBundle.getString("startTime"));
outBundle.putString("endDate", inBundle.getString("endDate"));
outBundle.putString("endTime", inBundle.getString("endTime"));
outBundle.putString("eventType", inBundle.getString("eventType"));
outBundle.putString("eventDescription", inBundle.getString("eventDescription"));
```

I know this is not the most elegant solution, but it works.