# How to keep my current fragment on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use 3 fragments in one activity and one of that fragment is set as default fragment in `onCreate()` method and others fragments are calling through some action, so when I rotate the screen the `onCreate()` method calling again and my current fragment are lost and the default fragment start again but I have to use the default fragment inside the `onCreate()` method. How can I keep my running fragment on rotate the screen.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` on activity manifest
here is examples:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: It works, I'll give you that. But I wonder: how can I make, in addition, that changes the XML variant depending on orientation as well? (it conserves the whole state, but uses same XMLs in retrieval; you know `layout/` instead of `layout-land/` etc. remains the same as drawback)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`setRetainInstance(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))in your onCreate method.

> To retain stateful objects in a fragment during a runtime configuration change:
>
> Extend the Fragment class and declare references to your stateful objects.
>
> Call setRetainInstance(boolean) when the fragment is created.
>
> Add the fragment to your activity.
>
> Use FragmentManager to retrieve the fragment when the activity is restarted.

[see documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) of how to handle configuration changes, there is a fragment section

Comment: setRetainInstance(true); is depracated... Check my answers..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using BottomNavigationView and I encountered the same problem. 
Solved it by checking if **savedInstanceState** is null or not before loading the default fragment.

```
if(savedInstanceState==null) {
   //This is the function you call onCreate to load your Fragments
   loadFragments(new MyDefaultFragment());
}
```