# How can I keep a fragment on screen rotation (AND with XML variants kicking in)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a complete app that uses one Activity to rule several fragments. I'd like that, when the screen rotates, the whole state of the Activity (and it's Fragments' stack) to remain the same **without having to wire all the SaveInstanceState** all by myself if possible. So, I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41129198/3692177) that provides almost what I need:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

This does the trick: all state remains the same (scrolls, current fragment, whatever). There's just **one single issue with it:** It doesn't switch the XML's layout variant (from `layout/*` to `layout-land/*` or vice-versa).

I am aware of Android Activity's Lifecycle and I have done this kind of things serializing whatever state needed to be kept before, but **yet**, I need to ask: isn't there a way **this easy** to make it do exactly the same it already does, but changing the XML variant as if `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` wasn't set at all, but at the same time harnessing its benefits? Or do I have to wire all the state logic manually and there's no way around it?