# Add button on tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, android-tabbed-activity

[image]

Hi.

I have tabbed activity, i have 10 fragment in my project and i added "Add Button" button to fragment 1.When i clicked this button, new button has created in linear layout.İts ok, but i have a problem after this.for example, if i go to different tab, my button will be erased.Why this is happening? How can i solve this problem?

Thanks :)

My "Add Button" code ;

```
public void AddButton(View page){    
       LinearLayout Lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);    
       Button but = new Button(getApplicationContext());
       but.setText("" + myVec2.size());
       myVec2.add(but);
       mylayout.addView(but);      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a list with buttons on your Fragment and on your onCreateView if that list isn't empty to recreate those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the buttons  `onPause()`
and recreating in `onResume()`

Comment: how can i use onPause or onResume ?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the number of buttons in a variable and put it in `OnSaveInstanceState`.
2. Restore it in `onCreateView` in numButtons variable.
3. If the variable is > 0, add the buttons in your view.
4. In your button OnClick, do numButton ++ whenever add button is pressed.

   ```
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)

           if (savedInstanceState != null) {
              numButtons = savedInstanceState.getInt(Statics.NUMBER_BUTTONS);
           } else {
              numButtons = 0;
           }

          if (numButtons > 0)
             for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
          / ** Your Add Button Code ** /
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
          outState.putInt(Statics.NUMBER_BUTTONS, numButtons);
          super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      }
   ```