# Cannot save fragment state during rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have several fragments in activity, changed by bottombar. I tried to implement fragment state handling by using [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)
The problem is that

```
    mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, TAG);
```

Returns the next error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
```

While debugging I have the next savedInstanceSet:

```
ArrayMap@5665, size = 4
 value[0]=Bundle
 value[1]="FragmentName"
 value[2]=FragmentManagerState
 value[3]={Integer}"0"
```

Please dont paste solutions like

```
 setRetainInstance(true),
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and so on, because I need to recreate fragment (different xml files for land and portrait).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code;

Add this line to menifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and add this function to your activity file,

```
 @Override
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       }
```

Comment: I cannot use this one, because I need to recreate 2 fragments from land/layout file. So is there any other solutions?

Comment: Never ever manually call `Lifecycle` methods. They are supposed to be called only by the OS. That being said, please consider removing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Include this in your manifest if you dont want to override config change

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" >
```

> This basically allows OS to handle orientation change for you if you dont want override onConfigChange  this code should work fine

Comment: I cannot use this one, because I need to recreate 2 fragments from land/layout file. So is there any other solutions?

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    
} try using this in fragment's onCreate

Comment: This method didnt help