# Save fragments state

Tags: android, fragment, bundle, state

I have several fragments in one activity. I want to save state of fragments when I switching between them. But activity don't recreated and `onSaveInstanceState` don't call. Can I somehow save bundle, for example, in `onPause` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `addToBackStack()` like this each time you create a new fragment.

```
if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new MyFragmentClass();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.your_fragment_id, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

The fragment will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

Comment: but what to do if I want to save additional data in the bundle?