# How to Make Everything (Counters, Variables) to null of an Object?

Tags: android, object, object-initialization, object-state

I want to know that how can I make a an Object again go back to its initial stage.
In my case I make a fragment and initialize it. I want that when it goes back to another fragment, and then back to first one, all values and variables of the first objects again initializes.

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
```

How can it again go back to this stage without initialization it again with new Keyword.

Comment: Add a function to reset the state within the constructor

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below setter technique

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

private String name;
private String address;

public void resetAll(){
    myFragment = null;
  }
}
```

Here myFragment is reference variable of fragment. After call of resetALL method, every String variable available in fragment will be null

Comment: But if it contains dofferet objects like array lists and some UI views?
What about them?

Comment: They all are part of fragment then if fragment is null then all references will automatically be null if the are being accessed through reference of fragment variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use setters.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    //other code
}
```

Now you can use

```
frag.setName(null);
```

You can also make a method to reset all the variables inside the `MyFragment` class.

```
public void reset(){
    name = null;
    //other stuffs = null
}
```

so that you can call `frag.reset();`