# How to Restore ViewPager from savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have a problem that I can't seem to solve. I have a ViewPager in one of my activities, say *MainActivity*. I am implementing all the required methods to save and retrieve instance state when the activity gets killed in the background. But when the activity tries to restore its state, the fragments are restored but they are not attached to the viewpager so all I get is a white screen.

Here is the relavant code:

***MainActivity.java***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //..
    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        setupViewPager();
    }
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.addFrag(FirstFragment.newInstance(mFeedItem), "INFO");
    //Note: mFeedItem is obtained from the intent and I have verified
    //      that it is properly restored.
    mAdapter.addFrag(SecondFragment.newInstance(mFeedItem), "SERVICES");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

***ViewPagerAdapter.java***

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

***FirstFragment.java***

```
public static FirstFragment newInstance(Workshop item) {
    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    f.mItem = item;
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("feed_item",Workshop.packToGson(mItem));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail_info, container, false);
    if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
        mItem = Workshop.extractGson(savedInstanceState.getString("feed_item"));
    }
    return v;
}
```

So if I navigate to another activity and then the `MainActivity` gets killed in the background ( I am using the [*Don’t Keep Activities*](https://android.jlelse.eu/aadt-4-test-with-low-end-devices-f44faf363116) setting to test this), this happens:

1) The Activity gets restored properly, no issues there.
2) The `onCreateView` of the fragments are called, with the `savedInstanceState` intact.
3) But, the ViewPager and Adapter in my Activity are `null`. The fragments dont seem to get attached back to the adapter/viewpager.

So what am I missing here? Am I supposed to do anything to properly restore the fragments?

### PS:

I am able to solve the issue quickly by replacing this in my `MainActivity`:

```
if (savedInstanceState==null) {
    setupViewPager();
}
```

with just `setupViewPager();`, so that a new adapter and fragments are created irrespective of whether it is restoring or launching for the first time. But that comes with the drawback of resetting the state of the fragments. Also, when I do that, I find that there are two instances of each fragment, one which is restored and a new one, with only the new instances actually displayed. So I dont believe that it is the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By destroying the `Activity` you also destroy every instance field. So you have to re-instantiate the `ViewPager` and `Adapter`. There are two scenarios you have to keep in mind.

1. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` saves/restores `Fragments` with the `FragmentManager`
2. You have to restore the state of the `Fragments` inside the `Fragment`

The first point is the reason why you have two instances of each `Fragment`. In order to fix this you can get the stored Fragment by its **ID**. [See this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#FragmentPagerAdapter.makeFragmentName%28int%2Cint%29) grepcode `FragmentPagerAdapter` (same goes for `StateAdapter`)

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```

Instead of instantiating a `Fragment` in `setupViewPager` every time - you get it from the `FragmentManager` first e.g.

```
mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
int fragmentCount = 2; // save value if it's a arbitrary list of fragments
for (int index = 0; i < fragmentCount; i++) {
    FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.view_pager, index));
    if (firstFragment == null) {
        firstFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance(mFeedItem);
    }
    mAdapter.addFrag(firstFragment, "someTitle");
}
```

The above is an example on how to restore previous saved `Fragments` from the `FragmentManager`. You probably have to adjust the cases where you have different types of `BaseFragments` and so on. Furthermore you might want to save the `Fragment` title names and the total count to restore them.

---

The second point is that you have to restore the current `Fragment` state from the `Fragment` itself. For that your `Fragment` has the lifecycle methods. See this SO topic about that [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

Comment: I tried this but the `findFragmentByTag` call is always null

Comment: @ShahiM If you did it correctly then it means the `Fragment` was not instantiated/saved in the first place. Then you have to make use if the `if-branch` to instantiate a new one.

Comment: Seems like it does not work for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I changed it to `FragmentPagerAdapter`and *all iz well*.

Comment: I followed all of this, because I had the same issue. It works after changing FragmenStatePagerAdapter to FragmentPagerAdapter, except the Fragments added to the ViewPager are invisible, like it's not inflated even though onViewCreated is called. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

FragmentStatePagerAdapter has method saveState() and restoreState() to save and restore it's state..

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html#saveState()

> saveState: Save any instance state associated with this adapter and its pages that should be restored if the current UI state needs to be reconstructed.

So it seems that it could be possible to use these methods to archive your goal. I'm sorry, but I don't have compiler now, so I couldn't tested code below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setupViewPager(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Parcelable parcelable = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Adapter");
        mAdapter.restoreState(parcelable, getClassLoader());
    } else {
        mAdapter.addFrag(FirstFragment.newInstance(mFeedItem), "INFO");
        //Note: mFeedItem is obtained from the intent and I have verified
        //      that it is properly restored.
        mAdapter.addFrag(SecondFragment.newInstance(mFeedItem), "SERVICES");
    }
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Parcelable parcelable = mAdapter.saveState();
    outState.putParcelable("Adapter", parcelable);
}
```