# Fragment containing ViewPager reloads when switched back from another Fragment using NavGraph - Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

(TLDR provided below)

I've a complex Activity-Fragment Structure which was earlier 3 Activities, now converted to three Fragments. Because it was complex, heavy and a lot of data was interchanged, I'd changed it to the new Navigation UI based structure looking at Google's Sunflower and it is much cleaner now and works faster and better.

My app's flow can easily be understood by the image provided below (Nav Graph provided below):
[image: Image describing my app's flow]

Main Fragment is `Fragment1` which contains the `ViewPager2` with `FragmentStateAdapter` and 5 Fragments inside it. The problem is `Fragment1` completely reloads when user comes back to it from `Fragment2`.

Two possible scenarios:

1. When user opens `Fragment2` from `Fragment1` and comes back, `Fragment1` which contains the `ViewPager` completely reloads which takes 2-3 seconds as it contains 5 `Fragment` which further consists of `Fragment` and is the problem I need the solution of.
2. As I'm using `ViewBinding`, If I check whether the binding has been initialized or not (code below) and pass initialized instead, the Fragment1 doesn't reload **but** Fragments inside the `ViewPager` get issues like any button in any Fragment will stop working, the `TabLayout` will stop working, Child `ViewPager2`s in `FragmentB`, `FragmentD and FragmentE` will stop working.

   ```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
       if (!this::binding.isInitialized) {
           //initializing Binding here
       }
       return binding.root
   }
   ```

---

1. Graph `nav_main.xml` with pictorial representation:
   [image]

   ```
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_main"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment_1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
            android:name="com.x.x.fragments.Fragment1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment_1_to_fragment_2"
                app:destination="@id/fragment_2"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment_1_to_fragment_3"
                app:destination="@id/fragment_3"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
            android:name="com.x.x.fragments.Fragment2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment_2_to_fragment_3"
                app:destination="@id/fragment_3"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

            <argument
                android:name="DataModel"
                app:argType="com.x.x.models.DataModel" />

            <argument
                android:name="Tab"
                app:argType="integer" />

        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_3"
            android:name="com.x.x.fragments.Fragment3"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_3">

            <argument
                android:name="DataModel"
                app:argType="com.x.x.models.DataModel" />

        </fragment>

    </navigation>
   ```
2. activity_main.xml

   ```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />

    </layout>
   ```

---

(TL;DR) So, My question is how can I prevent reloading of the `FragmentA` which contains the `ViewPager2` and ensure that Fragments inside it will not stop working? I've no problem if I can only prevent reloading of child `FragmentC`, the default one on which app opens, others can reload. Please note I've read almost all the (somewhat) similar questions and answers and none helps.

**EDIT** - I tried both of the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47108494/8244632) which I thought of getting success with, but nothing worked.

**EDIT2** - Found a similar popular question without any working solution - [Viewpager2 with fragments and Jetpack navigation: Restore fragments instead of recreating them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57271553/8244632)
.

**EDIT3** - I also tried saving the instance of the `ViewPager`'s adapter using the `saveState()` in `onStop()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` and restoring it using `restoreState()` but then, it shows nothing but a white screen.

**EDIT4** - I've searched their Github issues as well, found no solution. Is the only solution I've is to go back to Activities? Is there nothing to do with these Fragments?

Comment: You can do it with fragments (and other custom navigation frameworks that may wrap Fragments), but you cannot do it with Jetpack Navigation (without writing a custom navigator, which you probably won't)

Comment: Hey @EpicPandaForce So, how do you suggest going with the Fragments way, using a ViewPager like mechanism where it doesn't stop the previous Fragment? As in the Navigation, it calls `onStop()` when a fragment is switched to back stack and hence, doesn't work properly even by maintaining reference of previous view. And this custom Navigator seems interesting, can't I override the default fragment behaviour and prevents it from stopping even on backstack?

Comment: Well the behavior is inherent to using `replace().addToBackStack()`, if it was possible to use `add(new).hide(current)` on forward, and `remove(current).show(previous)` on back, then you can keep fragments without killing them. Bottom navigation currently can only keep fragments if you use nested child fragments. I'd love to link resources but apparently "self-attribution" is frown upon on this site, which is why I don't post here often anymore.

Comment: So, if I create a custom navigator and override the default procedure to load the fragment   of the fragment manager, at least in theory, this can be possible with my current scenario, I'll definitely check this custom navigator out before going with the Fragment way, Thank you, sir, and btw, any resources you share that can help are surely welcome.

Comment: Just add your fragments normally without navgraph then you can achieve what yuu want.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar check out this answer, might help. The user claims it as google's recommended solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142496/6172439

Comment: @DarshanMiskin I'd already checked it out before posting this question, this is meant for `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar from what I understood by that answer, apart from your main activity, the fragment1 or it's child which has multiple fragments inside it, in your case should have a nav-graph of it's own.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Hey, I had found a solution to this problem about two days later when you commented but forgot to post it because of covid. This upvote remimded me of this question, Thank you for your suggestion, I had created a custom navigator and instead of replacing the fragment, I hide it and it works flawlessly. I'll answer it later. Found no answer even on the official repo, but you helped..