# How do I preserve the fragment's state when I click away then come back in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-savedstate

When I move from one Fragment to the other, I want the state of it to stay the same and not restart every time I click back. For example the scroll position, what was clicked on, etc. Everything should remain the same.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack)

Comment: @0X0nosugar All of the solution's I've found include an OnRestoreInstanceState method but I don't thin Android's Fragment still includes this method.

Comment: I think for Fragment it's called onViewStateRestored()