# on Activity created restoring spinner objects

Tags: java, android, spinner

Since Fragments do not have the onRestore State I am trying to restore spinner objects once the app is relaunched. So how can I implement the below code to restore the selected items from a spinner?

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            spinnerItem = savedInstanceState
        }


    }
```

Comment: You can store the selected item in sharedpreferences and when you launch your application you can check sharedpreferences if value exist, if it does you can set the spinner to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help, previous comment is to be deleted so i posted a new one with a different response

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

private String[] choices = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};

// Initial position
private int spinnerPosition = 0;

private static final String SPINNER_ITEM_POSITION = "whatever_label_fits_you";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    // This part is here to simulate a real Spinner since your example didn't include one
    final AppCompatSpinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choices);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
        {
            spinnerPosition = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        spinnerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SPINNER_ITEM_POSITION);

    spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState)
{
    // Save current position to bundle so you can retrieve it in onCreateView
    outState.putInt(SPINNER_ITEM_POSITION, spinnerPosition);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}}
```

If it still doesn't help you can always check [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack) which answers to the question of how to save instance in fragments.
For this to work in your Activity just make sure you only create the Fragment when savedInstanceState in onCreate method is null, because otherwise you will lose all data that you saved, since you are always creating a new fragment.