# How to use different fragments depending on the actual orientation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I searched everywhere in the site and found no answer. So far I managed to keep important states of my App when orientation changes but now I want to have separate fragments for each orientation:

If (Portrait Mode) => attach fragment portrait to activity

if (Landscape Mode) => attach fragment landscape to activity

**I don't want just two separate layouts, but two different fragments** (this is because I want to add some functionality that's "impossible" to achieve in portrait mode). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for orientation changes in `onConfigurationChanged` of the activity that you're attaching your fragments.

So, what you need to do is,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //set the fragment for landscape mode
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
         //Set the fragment for portrait mode
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize`" in the activity tag in your manifest file that you're handling configuration changes.

Comment: It works! However now I loss my "state" (which is actually just an array) is there an easy way to still mantain my state? As far as I understand, when I change orientation, onConfigurationChanged is called and there I'm inflating the appropiate fragment but.. here there is no way to keep the state or is there?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack

Answer (score 1):

We suggest checking your orientation in onResume() method of your activity like bellow.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int mOrientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (mOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // code for portrait mode
            //Add your Portarait fragment
        } else {
            // code for landscape mode
            // Add your landscape fragment
        }
    }
```