# RecyclerView inside LinearLayout and NestedScrollView - How to scroll to top of item on a certain position?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I implemented RecyclerView. I would like a view scroll to top of item on 5th position in RecyclerView. `scrollToPosition(5)` don't work

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView_mark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_markView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_marks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible">
```

in Fragment:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(5);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You can handle it by saving clicked position and in onResume() you can perform scrollToPosition.
Add your coding part for a click, so anyone can review it.

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollToPosition()` needs to be used with any of the following ways to restore the scroll position to the selected position.You can save the selected  position in  `onPause()` and then restore subsequently.
There might be two useful ways :-

1. Using `onSaveInstanceState()` function to save the state as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/7200713).
2. Using Shared Prefereneces to store the position, and restoring the state after the `onCreateView`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is my first question and I have explained my problem wrong.  `scrollToPosition()`don't work. I set 5 permanently to check if it scrolls to position 5 in RecyclerView. Did not work

Comment: 'scrollToPosition(int position) ' the parameter specifies to the adapter position. In code that you shared  , try setting the adapter before calling 'scrollToPosition(int p)' .

Comment: I have set the adapter befor `scrollToPosition()` but didn't help :( Have you got another idea what is wrong?