# Hide the Floating Action Button from my Fragment and keep it hide even I change the orientation of the phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I could solve how to hide or show a Floating Action Button from a fragment when I call it.
But I faced with another problem that I didn't know how to solve it, when I rotate my phone, 
the FAB appears again.

You can see my code below and how I did to hide my FAB, but how to keep it when my phone rotate from 
Portrait to Landscape?

```
package com.example.cursobaralhocigano.ui.deck;


import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.example.cursobaralhocigano.MainActivity;
import com.example.cursobaralhocigano.R;
import com.example.cursobaralhocigano.classes.cBaralhos;
import com.example.cursobaralhocigano.dao.uLibSql;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DeckFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private uLibSql DB;
    private cBaralhos baralho = new cBaralhos();

    CheckBox ck01, ck02, ck03, ck04, ck05;
    ImageButton Img;

    public DeckFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        LinearLayout ln;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deck, container, false);

        final FloatingActionButton fab = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.fab);

        if (fab.isShown()) {
            fab.hide();
        }

return view;
}
```

Thanks a lot for help
Regards
Alex

Comment: Why don't you hide it in the XML and then show it using java code whenever you want

Comment: Hi Alok, 
How to do that? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Just find the XML code where you've defined your FloatingActionButton and use `android:visibility="gone"` and if you need to show it then in java code use `fabButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correctly save the instance state of Fragment you should do the following:

1. In the fragment, save instance state by overriding onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onActivityCreated():

Below link may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/10239870