# setOnMenuItemClickListener not navigating to my destination

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

so I only need to know when the user clicks on a certain menu item in my bottom navigation bar, the thing is that navigation works correctly if I put a `navController.navigate()` inside of this listener, but I don't want to do it because it messes with my cache state strategy, what I only want is to keep the bottom nav runing as always and navigating without any issues.

Only thing that I need to do is to register when the user clicks on that menu item, and I'm doing that with this

```
if(bottomNavigationBar.menu.getItem(3).isVisible) {
            bottomNavigationBar.menu.getItem(3).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                trackEvent()
                true
            }
        }
```

thing is that with this code it tracks when I click the menu item but it does not navigate to the destination

any one knows why I need to add `navController.navigate()` to this click event to navigate ? I don't want to do so

Comment: what is `trackevent()`  and why are you using inside menu click listener?

Comment: Because I need to track event when that menu item is clicked @Ramesh

Comment: okay, add condition in event() which menuID is clicked then call navigate() function

Comment: I cannot call navigate because it will mess with my saving state of that fragment

Comment: simply use replace  fragment function I think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack see more